# Autohotkey - need to run from Win7 taskbar an autohotkey script which uses another file

Tags: windows, autohotkey, taskbar

I've made a new toolbar in Win7 with a bunch of encrypted files stored in that toolbar folder. I want to be able to click any one of the items in that toolbar folder and run an autohotkey script on it to decrypt it and do other things in it. The encrypted files have a .enc extension (my choice), and let's say the ahk script I want to run is called decrypt.ahk. So my problems is that when I click any .enc file, windows, of course, needs to know what program the .enc file is associated with, and it has to be a .com .exe or .bat, which is not what I want. I need to associate the .enc file with the decrypt.ahk file. How do I do this?

If I tell windows to use autohotkey.exe for association it's going to run

```
autohotkey.exe file.enc
```

That won't work, decrypt.ahk has the code to decrypt.
I need this -

```
decrypt.ahk file.enc
```

Ok, here is the full code for decrypt.ahk

```
SetWorkingDir, w:\
;save encrypted filename.enc as variable encrfile
encrfile = %1%

;Pull out filename from filename.enc and save as variable called filename
StringTrimRight, filename, encrfile, 4

KeyWait, LButton, D

;decrypt to filename.ahk
runwait, "G:\app.exe" "G:\app.key" d %encrfile% %filename%.ahk,, hide

;run the script
runwait, %filename%.ahk
;delete the script
FileDelete %filename%.ahk
```

Comment: Could you compile your decrypt script?

Comment: That's a good idea. I will try. I also tried adding decrypt.ahk into a batch file and then associating that batch file with .enc files. It's sort of working. The code in decrypt.ahk waits for a left click before decrypting, but it does not work if I left click in my text editors. I have to left click in the windows taskbar or similar for the left click to be detected. Strange.

Comment: Maybe consider making it a `MsgBox` that you click OK to instead of waiting for clicks?

Comment: Update - Just tried the compiled version and yes it works except for the last line in the file which is "FileDelete". There is a "RunWait", then the "FileDelete" command. "RunWait" works but the file is not deleted. Is this something to do with permissions?

Comment: Strange, if I run the script from scite editor, it runs fine and the file is deleted.

Comment: I'd probably need to see your code (or a simplified version of it) to better address this issue. That would probably be better to put in a new question too.

Comment: Ok, I added my script. It's not large. I can put it in a new question if you think it's required. I still think this has something to do with permissions on Win7.